# datepicker doesnt update attribute tags when I select over option field a value

Tags: jquery

I got a option field, when I select a value there, I implemented a dynamic text over a div-tag. now I wana do the same wie a datepicker input field but the attributes change only on first time select, when I select a other value it doesnt change the attributes of the datepicker.

first time trying it and after online researche for the issue I didnt find a solution in 2 h. although I am new to jquery, so I guess its some inital issue.

Librarys I include on the website

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script src="JQuery/ui.js"></script>  in ui.js I programm the JQuery functions
```

website

```
<select id="optionfield" name="xxx">
  <option value="val1" .....
               </option>
<input type="text" id="datep" size="8">
```

ui.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#optionfield').change(function () {
    var selectval = $('#optionfield option:selected');
    switch(selectval.val()){
        case "val1": $('#divdynamicoutput').html('some text1'); 
            break;
        case "val2": $('#divdynamicoutput').html('some text2');
            break;
        case "val3": $('#divdynamicoutput').html('some text3');
            $(function() {
                       $("#datep").datepicker({
                          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                          minDate: 0,
                          beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
                             var day = date.getDay(); 
                             return [day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5 , ""];}
                          });
                       });
            break;
        case "val4": $('#divdynamicoutput').html('some text 4');
            $(function() {
                       $("#datep").datepicker({
                          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                          minDate: 0,
                          beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
                             var day = date.getDay(); 
                             return [day == 1 || day == 3 ,""];
                          }
                        });
            });
            break;
        default: $('#divdynamicoutput').html('text default');
    }  
 } 
});
```

at val3 and val4 I tryed to change the "beforeShowDay-tag" from the "datepicker->datep". val3 makes only mo-fr availabe and val4 mo and wed. when I select first time a value from option, the datepicker is correct, when I switch again an option on select, the datepicker doesnt refresh anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I seperated the selector datep from the switch:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datep").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 0,             
    });
});
```

in the switch I only call the konstructor with this parameter and code

```
$("#datep").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", function(date){  var day =
date.getDay();
return [day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5,""];
});
```

and now he changes the restictate days after every change of the selection field.

Thoughed first that the solution is something with reinitalize() or repaint(), actualy its somekind of reinitalizing. sry I am new in jquery dont know the basics, anyone can recommend a starter lecture for jquery?